# Audacity | Split | duplicate split-positions onto another layer

Tags: audio, editing, audacity, cut

`Audacity_2.1.2
win10_Home_x64`

## AUDACITY

- How to do a split

  - `Edit -> Clip-Boundaries -> Split`
  - *depending on whether it's a `point` vs. `selection`*
  - *`CTRL-I`*
- Point vs. Selection

  - Point
  - *A point will only be to where the cursor is placed and there isn't
    more than 1-cursor*
  - Selection
  - *To your current selection both the beginning-point & ending-point will
    be marked as splitted*

## DILEMMA

- **I want to be able to do the same `split` formatting to multiple tracks that are the same.**

  - *This is an extremely tedious process if the `split`-amount is like about 500-sectors.*

## EXAMPLE

[image]

---

### NOTE

- Having the ability to duplicate `split-points` from one layer to another
- will be more helpful with a *keybind keyboard shortcut hotkey*.

Answer (score 1):

A selection in one track may be extended to cover all tracks with the shortcut:
Ctrl+Shift+K

It's also in the Edit menu:
Edit > Select > In all tracks

The split command (Ctrl+I) will then be applied to all tracks.